# Aerospike losing documents when node goes down

Tags: amazon-web-services, aerospike

I've been doing dome tests using aerospike and I noticed a behavior different than what is sold.

I have a cluster of 4 nodes running on AWS in the same AZ, the instances are t2micro (1cpu, 1gb RAM, 25gb SSD) using the aws linux with the AMI aerospike

aerospike.conf:

```
heartbeat {
        mode mesh
        port 3002                        
        mesh-seed-address-port XXX.XX.XXX.164 3002
        mesh-seed-address-port XXX.XX.XXX.167 3002
        mesh-seed-address-port XXX.XX.XXX.165 3002
        #internal aws IPs
...
namespace teste2 {
        replication-factor 2
        memory-size 650M
            default-ttl 365d                                                                                                                    
        storage-engine device {
                    file /opt/aerospike/data/bar.dat
                    filesize 22G
                        data-in-memory false                                                                     
        }
}
```

What I did was a test to see if I would loose documents when a node goes down. For that I wrote a little code on python:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import aerospike
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
config = {
  'hosts': [ ('XX.XX.XX.XX', 3000),('XX.XX.XX.XX',3000),
             ('XX.XX.XX.XX',3000), ('XX.XX.XX.XX',3000)]
} # external aws ips
client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
for i in range(1,10000):
  key = ('teste2', 'setTest3', ''.join(('p',str(i))))
  try:
    client.put(key, {'id11': i})
    print(i)
  except Exception as e:
    print("error: {0}".format(e), file=sys.stderr)
  time.sleep(1)
```

I used this code just for inserting a sequence of integers that I could check after that. I ran that code and after a few seconds I stopped the aerospike service at one node for 10 seconds, using `sudo service aerospike stop` and `sudo service aerospike colstart` to restart.

I waited for a few seconds until the nodes did all the migration and executed the following python script:

```
query = client.query('teste2', 'setTest3')
query.select('id11')
te = []
def save_result((key, metadata, record)):
    te.append(record)
query.foreach(save_result)
d = pd.DataFrame(te)
d2 = d.sort(columns='id11')
te2 = np.array(d2.id11)
for i in range(0,len(te2)):
  if i > 0:
    if (te2[i] !=  (te2[i-1]+1) ):
      print('no %d'% int(te2[i-1]+1))
print(te2)
```

And got as response:

```
no 3
no 6
no 8
no 11
no 13
no 17
no 20
no 22
no 24
no 26
no 30
no 34
no 39
no 41
no 48
no 53
[ 1  2  5  7 10 12 16 19 21 23 25 27 28 29 33 35 36 37 38 40 43 44 45 46 47 51 52 54]
```

Is my cluster configured wrong or this is normal?

ps: I tried to include as many things I could, if you please suggest more information to include I will appreciate.

Comment: Have you implemented the Aerospike recommendations for running on EC2? For example interval = 150, heartbeat timeout = 20, pre-warming EBS etc. See http://www.aerospike.com/docs/deploy_guides/aws/recommendations/ for full list.

Comment: Ok. I changed the interval and timeout at the machines. Configured to distribute IRQ over multiple cores using RPS. Did the pre-warming thing. The instance status check at the EC2 dashbord is faulty for all 4 instances and I can't access the aerospike, amc nor via ssh. They just stop working...

Comment: Those recommendation would have little to do with this situation.

What version of Aerospike are you running?

Are you sure migrations had completed when you initiated the scan?

Comment: The [backup utility](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/backup/asbackup.html) will also print the number of records that were backed up and can target an individual set. To rule out client issues, could you take a backup and verify the count?

Comment: "Did the pre-warming thing. ...  I can't access the aerospike, amc nor via ssh" Sounds like you may have zeroized your root partition?

Comment: It is version 3.6.0 (the latest from the AWS Marketplace). There were no migrations happening at the time, I was checking via the amc http client. I can't access the instances no more, they are unavailable, if I try to attach the hd (volume) to another instance, could I perform a backup (I don't need the data, I just want to know what happened). And what do you mean by zeroized the root partition? (thanks so far by the way)

Comment: The command used to pre-warm a device overwrites the device with zeros. This would have certainly wiped you test data discussed here, but if you targeted the device where your root file system in mounted then you would have deleted your OS. If you did wipe your OS and you were using another device for Aerospike storage then you should be able to mount that to another instance.

Comment: Ok, but would that explain the loss of inserts? Any other idea?

Comment: Are you able to repeat these results? Could you try issuing both the query and regular gets to all the keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found a solution, and it is pretty simple and foolish to be honest.

In the configuration file we have some parameters for network communication between nodes, such as:

```
interval 150                    # Number of milliseconds between heartbeats
timeout 10                      # Number of heartbeat intervals to wait
                                # before timing out a node
```

This two parameters set the time it takes to the cluster to realize the node is down and out of the cluster. (in this case 1.5 sec).

What we found useful was to tune the write policies at the client to work along this parameters.

Depending on the client you will have some policies like number of tries until the operation fails, timeout for the operation, time between tries.

You just need to adapt the client parameters. For example: set the number of retries to 4 (each is executed after 500 ms) and the timeout to 2 sec. Doing that the client will recognize the node is down and redirect the operation to another node.

This setup can be overwhelming on the cluster, generating a huge overload, but it worked for us.